# Calculate Sum of three "EUR xxx,xx" values in PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working with Amazon API at the moment and it returns the lowest available price in the format: "EUR xxx,xx" (for example "EUR 23,99").

Now I want to calculate the sum of three prices, but since the value is not just numbers I have no idea how to do this.

I tried

```
$a = $ergebnis['price1'];
$b = $ergebnis['price2'];
$c = $ergebnis['price3'];
$string = "a + b + c";

$result = eval('return ' . preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/', '\$$1', $string) . ';');
echo $result;
```

But this did not return a result.

Comment: is $a = "EUR", $b = xxx and $c =xx ??

Comment: No,

$a = EUR xxx,xx
$b = EUR xxx,xx
$c = EUR xxx,xx

Comment: Stay away from eval(). Far, far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow 2 steps:

- remove "EUR ",
- convert to `float`

To remove "EUR " explode string by space with explode `explode(" ", $price)[1]`. Then you want to change commas to dots and convert to float, this can be done by `floatval()` and `str_replace()`.

```
function toFloat($price) {
  return floatval(str_replace(',', '.', explode(" ", $price)[1]));
}

$a = toFloat($ergebnis['price1']);
$b = toFloat($ergebnis['price2']);
$c = toFloat($ergebnis['price3']);
$result = $a + $b + $c;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Using `str_replace` and `explode` use more memory and CPU cycles than Regex, which operates at byte level.

Comment: @mwieczorek I just checked both of our codes with 1mln iterations. Your code is 30-40% slower than mine. Changing `floatval()` to `(float)` makes the difference 40-55%.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex:

```
$string = 'EUR 23,99';

function currencyToFloat($string) {
    return (float) preg_replace("/^[A-Z]{3}\s([\d]+)[,.]([\d]+)/", "$1.$2", $string);
}
```

It will convert a three-letter currency code, plus a space, then any number (European or International formatted) into a float value.

```
echo currencyToFloat($string); // EUR 23,99 --> 23.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the separators (for decimals comma to dot, and for thousands dot to comma) and you will be able to sum them:

```
$price1 = explode(" ", $ergebnis['price1']);
$price2 = explode(" ", $ergebnis['price2']);
$price3 = explode(" ", $ergebnis['price3']);

$a = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $price1[1])));
$b = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $price2[1])));
$c = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $price3[1])));

$result = $a + $b + $c;
echo $result;
```

Comment: You are forgetting about the currency part (`EUR 24.99` is not parseable with floatval according to the docs).

Comment: Right, I didn't noticed that you had that, sorry. I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

u can use .split(" ") on every EUR 23,99.

```
var str = "EUR 23,99";
var result = str.split(" ");
```

split returns an array of items that are divided by a delimiter, in this example ites " " so u will get EUR as result[0] and 23,99 as result[1] so u can convert all into the same currency and convert number from string and add them to the sum

Answer (score -2):

I guess that you receive strings from the API. You can calculate with them by simply converting them to numbers:

```
$a = floatval($ergebnis['price1']);
$b = floatval($ergebnis['price2']);
$c = floatval($ergebnis['price3']);
```

The function `floatval();` returns the float value.

Comment: See [example 2 in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) to see how `floatval` behaves on a string like `EUR 24,99` (eg. non-numeric leftmost character).

Comment: I guess removing characters from a string is not much of a problem, but okay: `preg_replace("/[^0-9.,]+/g", "", $only_numbers);`